# PHP - Opencart - Paypal 3d secure payment using credit cards

Tags: paypal, opencart, 3d-secure

Is there any extension/module for Paypal 3d secure payment using credit cards in opencart other than UK? If it is there, let me know the process flow of 3d secure payment.

Comment: I'm not sure if PayPal uses `3d secure`, anyway You could use the **Paypal web standard** (not the UK version) and have a credit card registered within Your paypal account that You pay by... So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If bank issued you a credit card with 3d secure, you can't pay, paypal can't get money from your account if 3d secure isn't supported.